# How does developer identify their operating system kernel type?

Tags: kernel

I've been writing my operating system for about 6 months but i need to know what kernel type my operating system is, i mean like microkernel, monolithic kernel and stuff like that.

I have been coding an operating system for myself. It used Linux kernel. Now i have tried to test my own skill on making a lightweight kernel.

My kernel works well and there is no error, but it is slow. I expected i coded from a monolithic kernel to microkernel because i heard microkernel takes much memory and my computer is pre-built with 1GB of RAM.

So finally, my question is: How do developers identify that their operating system kernel type is microkernel or monolithic kernel? Microsoft identify Windows XP as hybrid and GNU identify Linux as a monolithic kernel operating system.

Comment: C tag removed as it is irrelevant to your question

Comment: Microkernels have been in use since the late 1970's with their memory limits. And the Amiga from the mid 1980's used a microkernel architecture and originally ran on a system with only 256 KiB of RAM (and no virtual memory or paging), and it is (arguably) considered one of the best and fastest multi-tasking systems for a long time. So 1 GiB should be plenty.